# What does ~constructorName(); do?

Tags: c++, class

```
class LTexture
{
    public:

        LTexture();

        ~LTexture(); // what does it do exactly?
};
```

Comment: Please have a look at this [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) list.

Comment: This is the destructor. Lookup your textbook what's it's purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~constructorName()` is the class's [*destructor*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor), which gets called when the object goes out of scope or `delete` is called. The destructor is used for cleanup code, such as freeing memory and closing files.